# Wordpress Menu Wrapping on twenty twelve child

Tags: css, wordpress, navigationbar, word-wrap

jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/shajar93/q3xg37bs/

I can't seem to stop my navigation menu from wrapping. I'm still a beginner with CSS and child themes, so please be patient with me if the answer is blatantly obvious!

I will also be adding another tab in the near future (currently 8 tabs on the menu), so once this is resolved for now, I will need to make sure the menu will accommodate the extra tab and not wrap again.

Here's the CSS

```
#navigation {
background: #464646;
min-height: 40px;
width: 100%;
}

#navigation .btn-navbar {
    background: url('img/nav-collapse.png') no-repeat;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 53px;
}

#navigation .caret {
    border-bottom-color: #fff;
    border-top-color: #fff;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

#navigation ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#navigation ul li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

#navigation ul li.active {
    background: #fff;
}

#navigation ul li:first-child a {
    border-left: 1px solid #333;
}

#navigation ul li a {
    border-right: 1px solid #333;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#navigation ul li.active a {
    color: #333;
}

#navigation ul li:hover a,
#navigation ul li a:hover {
    background: #fff;
    color: #333;
}

#navigation ul li.active .caret,
#navigation ul li:hover .caret,
#navigation ul li a:hover .caret {
    border-bottom-color: #333;
    border-top-color: #333;
}

#navigation ul li:hover ul {
    left: -4px;
}

#navigation ul li ul {
    background: #FFF;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #EEE;
    border-right: 4px solid #EEE;
    border-left: 4px solid #EEE;
    left: -999em;
    width: 220px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2000;
}

#navigation ul li ul li {
    width: 100%;
}

#navigation ul li ul li a {
    border: none !important;
    color: #333333;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Try setting a `min-width` attribute on the `#navigation` selector.

Comment: i've given it a try with mins of 600-1800px, but no luck. It just moves to the right above a min of 1500px

Comment: Please update the code with relevant html. Try to format it as a snippet or, if you find it easier, make a jsFiddle with it.

Comment: Sorry that took so long, I have edited the post to include the jsfiddle link